# Fatal Error : when get child block using controller

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers

When get block using controller got fatal error like

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getPostUrl() on null in
>   /app/design/frontend/theme/Vendor_Module/templates/post/list/item.phtml
>   on line 16

**Here is controller.**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Category;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $category_postdata = $objectManager->get('\Vendor\Module\Model\PostFactory');

        $layout = $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();

        $_postCollection = $category_postdata->create()->getCollection();
        $_postCollection->addCategoryFilter(['in' => $id]);

        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resultJsonFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory')->create();

        $resultPage = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory')->create();
        $block_set = $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Index')->setTemplate('post/list.phtml');
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Post\PostList\Item')
                ->setTemplate('post/list/item.phtml')
                ->setChild('test.posts.list.item',$block_set)
                ->setPost($_postCollection)
                ->toHtml($_postCollection);

        $response = $resultJsonFactory->setData($block);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

**Here is item.phtml**

```
<?php
$_post = $this->getPost();
$_postUrl = $_post->getPostUrl(); // line num 16
$_postName = $block->escapeHtml($_post->getTitle(), null, true);
?>

<li class="post-holder col-sm-4 col-xs-12   post-holder-<?php echo $_post->getId() ?>">

    <div class="">
        <div class="post-images">
            <a href="<?php echo $_post->getPostUrl() ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $block->resize($_post->getThumbnailimage(),335,280); ?>"/>
            </a>
            <h2 class="post-title-hover ">
                <a class="post-item-link"
                   href="<?php echo $_postUrl ?>">
                    <?php echo $_postName; ?>
                </a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="post-title-holder clearfix">
            <h2 class="post-title">
                <a class="post-item-link"
                   href="<?php echo $_postUrl ?>">
                    <?php echo $_postName; ?>
                </a>
            </h2>
        </div>

    </div>

</li>
```

**Here is block**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Post;

class PostList extends \Vendor\Module\Block\Post\PostList\AbstractList
{

    public function getPostHtml($post)
    {
        return $this->getChildBlock('test.posts.list.item')->setPost($post)->toHtml();
    }

}
```

Comment: try to debug variable `$_postCollection` in your controller file after line `$_postCollection->addCategoryFilter(['in' => $id]);`. it is getting desired data or not. If it will output  array of objects if it works well the you need to handle array.

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Yes you are right, but in this case isn't working. So i try to call new template and in block after collection get with encode and decode in template file. Now work for me.

Comment: sounds good that it is fixed. please input your fix as answer so some other buddy might get help . thanks

Comment: Sure, I will input my answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result using collection in template file, please check below.

**../post/list/item.phtml**

```
<?php

$blockObject= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Post\PostList\Item');

$id = $blockObject->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 

$_post = $this->getPost();

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$postFactory = $objectManager->get('\Vendor\Module\Model\PostFactory');
$catFactory = $objectManager->get('\Vendor\Module\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->getCollection();
$_postCollection = $postFactory->create()->getCollection();

$json = json_encode($_postCollection->getData());
$array = json_decode($json, true); ?>
<ol class="post-list" id="cat_post">
    <?php foreach ($array as $arr) {

    $postdata = $objectManager->create('\Vendor\Module\Model\Post')->load($arr['post_id']);
    $catId = $postdata->getCategories();
    if(in_array($id, $catId)){?>
        <li>
            <?php // Put your code here. ?>
        </li>
    <?php } } ?>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace,

```
$_postCollection = $category_postdata->create()->getCollection();
$_postCollection->addCategoryFilter(['in' => $id]);
```

With below,
Please replace,

```
$_postCollection = $category_postdata->create()->getCollection();
$_postCollection->addCategoryFilter(['in' => $id]);
$_postCollection = $_postCollection->getFirstItem();
```